# sass 7-1 architechture - Angular project

Tags: angular, sass

I am planning to adopt the 7-1 sass architecture pattern for my angular project as mentioned in the following articles

1. https://aaronverones.medium.com/using-the-7-1-sass-scss-pattern-with-angular-7-bb210c015dcc
2. https://sass-guidelin.es/#architecture

after reading the above articles I felt that it shows the better way to organize the styles, however wanted to know from the community about the other approaches or best practices on this aspect.

Please advice, thanks in advance.